# I want to write In a CSV file Under Movies directory of the internal storage

Tags: java, android

I want to write In a CSV file Under Movies directory of the internal storage. How can i create a .CSV file and how can i write something into it. it should work in latest android like Android 11. I'm using below code But this code actually throwing Open Failed EPERM (operation not permitted) Exception:

```
file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES) + "/NewFolder","newFile.csv");

    FileOutputStream f;
    try {
        f = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
        try {
            String title = "X Coord, Y Coord, Z Coord, Accelerometer\n";
            f.write(title.getBytes());
            f.flush();
            f.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: I want to write In a CSV file Under Movies directory of the internal storage. How can i create a .CSV file and how can i write something into it. it should work in latest android like Android 11.

Answer (score 0):

> > I want to write In a CSV file Under Movies directory

On an Android 11+ device your app is only allowed/permitted to create movie files in the Movies directory.

A file with a .csv extension will not go.

If you give the file an mp3 extension it will succeede.

Try the public Documents directory instead for a *.csv file.